# How do I customize directive template based on attribute in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-services, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make an cell into an input if it's set to editable by an column definition variable but I'm not very successful. This is my directive

```
app.directive('bsCell', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data : '=',
      editable : '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: function(tElement, tAttrs){
      console.log("---"); 
      console.log(tAttrs.editable);
      console.log(tElement); 

      var templateEdit = '<input class="form-control" ng-model="data">{{editable}}';
      var templateRead = '{{data]}}{{editable}}'; 
      return tAttrs.editable ? templateEdit : templateRead;
    },
  };
});
```

And here's an plnkr demonstrating the problem http://plnkr.co/edit/Nl5NHBvwh9FErFhu1GU8?p=preview
Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Template switching is not supported and in this particular scenario probably not the best idea anyway. Directive definition is simply supposed to load the component. Any other logic should be within the component anyway.

So your template can be

```
<div>
<div ng-show="editable" ><input class="form-control" ng-model="data">{{editable}}</div>
<div ng-show="!editable">{{data}}{{editable}}</div>
</div
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as I've got the ng-repeat on the element containing the data/input (an td in my case). I can't afford to put in added markup in my use case and it wouldn't be good semantics anyway. I solved it with post linking recompilation of the input cells as it's the quickest solution with best scalable performance for me and it doesn't add non semantic markup.